Calculate the contributions of percentage change of a ratio compossed by a/b
I would like to know how to calculate the change contribution to a ratio a/b where b is equal to a plus other variables: b = a + c+ d + e + f
I have seen the usual contributions to gdp growth in several places, but those approaches do not capture the contribution change to the share ratios of each component. What I mean is that the a/b ratio may change because a changes or because the other components that compose b.
The other sources I mentioned are:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33889/calculate-relative-contribution-to-percent-change
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/calculating-contribution-percent-change-jay-sumners-mia-lssgb/
